# Почему что-то устаканивается?

Tags: фразеология

Есть поговорка (или просторечное выражение - не знаю, какое тут определение подходит больше), что что-то устаканилось, то есть, уладилось.
А вот интересно, почему речь о стакане? Имеется в виду, что конфликтующие стороны выпили и помирились? Или что-то другое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

От Марины Королёвой:

Когда всё *устаканится*... Симпатичное словечко - *устаканится*. Успокоится, придет в норму, устоится. Собственно, никаких особых пояснений тут не нужно, все мы знаем, что такое *устаканиться*, и пользуемся этим словом довольно часто. Но у немногих из нас возникает вопрос: почему именно *устаканиться?* Какое отношение к этому глаголу имеет существительное "стакан"?

Начнем с того, что слово *"устаканиться"*, несмотря на его широкую употребительность, числится среди жаргонных. Если вы поставите перед собой задачу найти его в словарях, обнаружите только в Большом словаре русского жаргона да в Словаре арготизмов. Причем первый из упомянутых словарей полагает, что слово *"устаканиться"* относится к молодежному жаргону. Возможно, так поначалу и было, но сейчас оно явно вышло за эти рамки.

Что касается связи со словом *"стакан"*, то она прямая. Собственно, и версий-то других нет! Почему *устаканиться* - это успокоиться, прийти в норму? Возможно потому, что напитки, разлитые по стаканам, попадают в ограниченное пространство этих самых стаканов. А значит, некоторым образом *"успокаиваются"* в них... Такое вот предположение.

http://russia-west.ru/viewtopic.php?id=709

Answer (score 4):

Конфликт, спор, ссора между людьми определённой категории нередко разрешаются и завершаются с помощью налитых стаканов.

Comment: Это наиболее вероятная версия. Выпить вместе в момент примирения - важнейший ритуал и в те годы, когда гранёный стакан был одним из самых распространённых сосудов, и сейчас, когда его можно назвать раритетом.

Comment: Стакан это мера, разлитый вровень уравнивает  не только в правах, но и в степени.
Мировая достигалась, как правило, при помощи стакана и застолья.  Это касалось как торговых сделок, так и при решении политических проблем. Хлеб соль знаменитое, всегда закуска после стакана, и никак иначе. А без него и есть то незачем.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре жаргона только высказано предположение, что (возможно) слово  произошло от "разлить по стаканам". У меня же чисто интуитивно оно всегда ассоциировалось с успокоением уровня свеженалитой в стакан жидкости (или "буря в стакане воды" могла бы улечься). А если порассуждать, то можно предположить, что исходная ассоциация связана с обретением формы изменчивой сущностью: прояснившаяся ситуация (принявшая определённые "очертания") подобна жидкости, принявшей форму сосуда.

Answer (score 0):

Когда внешнее и внутреннее состояния входят в резонанс. Почему вы сделали привязку устаканиться к стакану? Я не слышал такого выражения: стаканиться. Чокаться можно, а вот стаканиться нет. Зато можно в поезде, привыкнув к раскачиванию вагона,  пить обжигающий кипяток не расплескивая его. Или например биатлонист,  при стрельбе,  должен совместить дыхание, мушку, ветер.  И таких примеров масса. И значит стакан не более чем совпадение букв.

Comment: А вы слышали слово "блажать"? Или - "спокоить"? Невзирая на это, русскоязычное население спокойно себе ублажается и успокаивается.